# how to display the php data in a input text field

Tags: php, html

I want to the display my data in a input text field. But i try many times and do not know the way. Can anyone helps?
Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Your Profile</h1>

<form action="exercise2.php" method="post">
<p>Firstname:
<input type="text" name="fname">
</p>

<p>Lastname:
<input type="text" name="lname">
</p>

<p>Address :
<input type="text" name="address">
</p>

<p>Birthday:
<input type="text" name="birthday" id="inputField">
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="save">
</p>

</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
  new JsDatePick({
   useMode:2,
   target:"inputField",
   dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
  });
 };
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

and my php codes:

```html
<?PHP

$first_name = $_POST["fname"];
$last_name = $_POST["lname"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$birthday = $_POST["birthday"];


list($bd,$bm,$by)=explode('-',$birthday);
$age=date('Y')-$by;



echo $first_name;
echo "<br>";
echo $last_name;
echo "<br>";
echo $address;
echo "<br>";
echo $birthday;
echo "<br>";
echo $age;
?>
```

I want to all the data in my php codes can be display in a input text field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to  add a value tag in your input field. and put your variable there to show value in a input box.
look like this, here value of  `$first_name;` will show in input field

`<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $first_name;` ?>">

if you want you variable on other pages than put values in session

```
 <?PHP
    session_start(); // start session
    // assign value in session 
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST["fname"];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST["lname"];
    $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST["address"];
    $_SESSION['birthday'] = $_POST["birthday"];


    list($bd,$bm,$by)=explode('-',$birthday);
    $_SESSION['age'] =date('Y')-$by;
   ?>
```

now you can see your all form values in session array

Now make other php file in same folder(project foler) & write

```
<?php 
 session_start(); // don't forget to start session
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: i see this code, it was display in the same html, but i want to display in a new html, can this way work?

Comment: yes why not,if your values in sessions or database than you can show them any where on a webpage or in any form of html. here a tutorial about save form data and show data in a page by php http://nyphp.org/PHundamentals/5_Storing-Data-Submitted-Form-Displaying-Database

Comment: sorry i tried, but it did not work......................

Comment: are you want show your form data in exercise2.php

Comment: No,I want to show form data in a new page...

Comment: than you need to store them first in db or session because you can use variable value only on single page ,only session variable are available on all pages

Comment: i have make some changes in my answer try them And Don't forget session_start(); on top of page otherwise session will not work